# When deploying old GWT app to Tomcat, RPC URL returns 404

Tags: spring, tomcat, gwt

I'm moving old GWT app from one server to another. Both in Eclipse and on old Tomcat everything is working OK, but on new server GWT app gets loaded (so the server is working and serving files), but fails on RPC call returning 404.

My admin and I have looked at possible differences in context paths, Tomcat and Java versions, and tried to recreate config on the new server as close as possible but it seems that we're missing something so I'm looking for fresh ideas.

As mentioned on [this link under common pitfalls](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideImplementingServices), it indicates that web.xml is misconfigured, but this is ruled out as the same web.xml works OK on old server. My @RemoteServiceRelativePath is "app.rpc" and in web.xml this is mapped to:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.rpc</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

...and in dispatcher servlet this is mapped to a correct controller. I can also give server.xml or any other part of config if needed, but I'm looking for other things that could be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, but by going nuclear and copying the exact same Tomcat and Java version with the same paths and all settings as on the old server. What I do know is that it was not a network problem, and that the request was received by Tomcat but never got to GWT or application code; so either Tomcat (5.5 in original configuration, 6.0 in the) or Spring (2.0.2) is the culprit. This is the old application that won't be updated and is due to be replaced and I hope it dies a quick and painless death.